# I am implementing ADFS - SAML configuration in wildfly18?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0, picketlink, wildfly-18

1) I have configured ADFS (SAML) configuration in wildfly18 server

2) I have all details configured in picketlink.xml as follows:
[image]

3) I am getting proper response in NAMEID format as follows:
[image]

4)But at server side I am getting error as follows:
[image]

5) I have checked the timing of ADFS server and My server both timezones are same.

can anyone me guide me on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The skew on Wildfire is set to an hour?

Have you tried making the ADFS skew larger? e.g.

Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetIdentifier "RP" -NotBeforeSkew 5

set the skew to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In the picketlink.xml Option keys are case sensitive, my clock_skew_millies property was written in camel case thus, the issue arrived. Once I have converted into all CAPS , the issue resolved